# How to create a class which is using existing classes?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I've written a programm which is creating a MenuCard for restaurants. In my code you can see that there are three classes created. Now, I want to make a class called 'ThreeCourseMenu' which is using all of those three existing classes. At this class 'ThreeCourseMenu' must be guaranteed, that there are not existing more (or exactly) than 3 Courses. How can I create this class using all of the three other classes?

Here is my code:

```
#class definitions
class MenuCard():
    __date : str
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.__date = date

    def add_course(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return '\nMenü vom {}\n'.format(self.__date)

class Course():
    __name : str
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name
        self.__dishes = []

    def add_dish(self, dish_name):
        self.__dishes.append(dish_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.__name)
        for i in self.__dishes:
            return i

class Dish(): 
    __name : str
    __veggie : bool
    def __init__(self, name, veggie):
        self.__name = name
        self.__veggie = veggie

    def __str__(self):
        if self.__veggie is True:
            return '{} (veg)'.format(self.__name)
        else:
            return '{}'.format(self.__name)

#creating class instances
MenuDate = MenuCard('10.11.2020')
vorspeise = Course('Vorspeise')
vorspeise_gericht = Dish('Carpaggio vom Rind auf knackigem Blattsalat', False)
vorspeise_gericht2 = Dish('Gemischter Salat mit Dressing nach Tradition', True)

suppe = Course('\nSuppe')
suppe_1 = Dish('Rindsuppe mit Beilage nach Wahl', False)

gang_eins = Course('\n1. Gang')
gang_speise_1 = Dish('Salat mit Toppings nach Wahl', True)

gang_zwei = Course('\n2. Gang')
gang_speise_2 = Dish('Schweinsbraten mit Kartoffelsalat', False)
gang_speise_3 = Dish('Rindersteak mit gebratenem Gemüse', False)
gang_speise_4 = Dish('Wienerschnitzel mit Pommes', False)
gang_speise_5 = Dish('Linsen-Chili mit Reis', True)

nachspeise = Course('\nNachspeise')
nachspeise_1 = Dish('Apfelkuchen mit Vanillesauce', True)
nachspeise_2 = Dish('Schokoschnitte mit Schlagsahne', True)

#list for all instances to loop over
gang = [vorspeise, vorspeise_gericht, vorspeise_gericht2, suppe, suppe_1, gang_eins, gang_speise_1, gang_zwei,
        gang_speise_2, gang_speise_3, gang_speise_4, gang_speise_5, nachspeise, nachspeise_1, nachspeise_2]

#output
print(MenuDate.__str__())
for food in gang:
    gang_text = food.__str__()
    print(gang_text)
```

Here I have tried to create this class, but I don't know why I need those three classes exactly. The Program gives me an AttributeError back and I don't know why. How can I solve this or is there another way to do that?

```
class ThreeCourseMenu():
    __menucard : MenuCard
    __course : Course
    __dish : Dish
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        count_courses = 0
        while count_courses <= 3:
            return self.__course
            count_courses += 1
        if count_courses == 3:
            print("There are exactly 3 courses")
        elif count_courses > 3:
            print("There are more than 3 courses")
        else:
            print("There are not more than 3 courses")
```

Comment: Did you try and solve this? If you did, please include that code. If you didn't, please try to and then re-submit with what's failing.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to write the class in the main code. Now it is available to see.

Comment: I’d recommend reading https://realpython.com/lessons/class-and-instance-attributes/